# MethodNotFoundException Jackson XmlMapper.coercionConfigDefaults()

Tags: java, spring, jackson, jboss

when I start my local Jboss I got the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MutableCoercionConfig com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.coercionConfigDefaults()'
```

1. I use the newest Version of Jackson and the method exists in the class XmlMapper.
2. Dependency tree looks good. All Versions of Jackson are the same.

Does anyone got a solution or had to deal with the same issue?

Comment: If a method you know exists, doesn't exist at runtime, then you are for sure not running with the jar versions you think you are. Check that you are actually using *only* the latest version jars at runtime.

Comment: Can you please check the scope of your dependency. And if that dependency is available during runtime. May be a good idea to share the snippet of where you added the dependency

Comment: @Jorn i already deleted my repository. Only the newest jackson version is in there.

Comment: @olzen Still, you should check your *actual* runtime classpath.

Comment: Thank you guys! The problem has been fixed. My Jboss has delivered a older jackson version. After making an exclusion it worked fine!

Comment: What version of Wildfly or JBOss EAP are you using?